# How to download Heroku slug?

Tags: git, github, heroku

I used GitHub to upload to Heroku and somehow by mistakes those commits are deleted from GitHub and my source code. I'm back to my old code and have lost some work.

I tried to restore using [How can I download my code from Heroku](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku) but because I didn't use Heroku Git instead I used GitHub one and those commits are now deleted I can download it even via Heroku slug plugin. They are giving me old commits.

I knew I should've make a zip file backup before doing something stupid playing with Git. Those were production files and I've no backup. Only files are now deployed to Heroku is working. but Heroku slug plugin is giving me old files with are present as commit on GitHub not deleted one.

How can I download Heroku current slug files?

Answer (score 5):

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs
```

Then this

```
heroku slugs:download -a Your App name
```

Comment: As I already mention in my question this one didn't work because it's giving me repository from github which is old one. new one somehow got deleted from both github and my pc. because I write some nonsense git commands.

Comment: Did you try also Heroku clone to get current files from the last deploy to Heroku?

Comment: The `heroku slugs:download` command downloads the compiled slug that was built when your application was last deployed. It is not a copy of your git repository. If you've managed to accidentally deploy a bad release, it might be that you're downloading this bad slug.

You can pass a UUID to the download command to specify an older release. use `heroku slugs -a APP_NAME` to locate the UUID for the release, and then `heroku slugs:download UUID -a APP_NAME`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to rollback to that version and them pull it down locally ?

1. check `heroku releases` to check the version you wish to rollback to
2. `heroku rollback v10` **10** is the older version  of your choice
3. `git log --reflog` to see view and copy your commit id
4. git checkout `commit id`
5. `heroku git:clone -a APP-NAME` to download current version

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer work. Turns out I was working in wrong branch.

Initially I worked on another branch then I did something, God knows what, I moved to master brach and my commits get deleted from github and I was moved to master branch which didn't have the latest code

So I moved to branch which I was working.

```
git checkout <another branch>
```

And there it was, all my latest code.

I moved to master branch.

```
git checkout master
```

I stashed the master branch changed.

```
git stash
```

I reset the master branch HEAD with my another branch

```
git reset --hard <another branch>
```

Then push all files to master branch on github.

```
git add -A
git commit -m "Recovered Files"
git push origin master --force
```